# Changing multiple instances of a similar element in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am currently trying to make a simple hangman game. For this section i am trying to replace the dashed lines with the letter given by the user input. However for words with repeat letters like 'apple' with two letter 'p' i encounter problems.

simplified example of my code:

```
word = ['a','p','p','l','e']
guess = 'p'
line = ['_','_','_','_','_']
for char in word:
    if guess == char:
        index = int(word.index(char))
        line[index] = char
```

output for print(line) will simple give ['*','p','*','*','*'], replacing only 1 'p' in the list. Any idea how to replace for both the 'p's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do next:

```
word = ['a','p','p','l','e']
guess = 'p'
line = ['_','_','_','_','_']

for idx, char in enumerate(word):
    if guess == char:
        line[idx] = char

print(line) # ['_', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']
```

The same in one line using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
line = [char if char == guess else '_' for char in word]
print(line) # ['_', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']
```

Comment: it's better to use
"line = [guess if char == guess else char for char in word]"
to avoid introducing another string.

Comment: @RonMarcelino first is updated OP solution, second is improved by list comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate),

```
word = ['a','p','p','l','e']
guess = 'p'
line = ['_','_','_','_','_']
for index, char in enumerate(word):
    if guess == char:
        line[index] = char
line
```

OR

Use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
line = [i if i == guess else '_' for i in word]
```

output

`['_', 'p', 'p', '_', '_']`